# sales_order_place_after event not working

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I trying to execute my second observer which reacts to when Place order button has been clicked (`sales_order_place_event`). My first observer  running good but second observer isn't. Could anybody tell me why? what am i doing wrong here?
**config.xml**

```
<events>
    <controller_front_init_before>
        <observers>
            <test_capture>
                <class>Foo_Test_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>capture</method>
                <type>singleton</type>
            </test_capture>
        </observers>
    </controller_front_init_before>
    <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <test_order>
                <class>Foo_Test_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>order</method>
                <type>singleton</type>
            </test_order>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
```

**Observer.php**

```
class Foo_Test_Model_Observer {

    public function capture(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        /*some code*/

    }

    public function order(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

        echo __LINE__;exit;

    }
}
```

I tried to put my method in `<controller_front_init_before>` and run.. it works but my `<sales_order_place_after>` is not working

Comment: children tag  of <observers> must unique.

Comment: fyi i am using third party extension for onepagecheckout and whenever i am clikcing on place order nothing hapening.

Comment: I think can third party extension conflict with your theme.

Comment: but orders are being added in backend

Comment: because in function order of you, you using exit, so orders are being added in backend

Comment: if that is the reason then why isn't it printing line number

Comment: You should using Mage::log('Success', null, 'mylog.log', true); to check avoid error "cannot send header header already sent"...

Comment: [Here is what I used to made it work](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91470/observer-code-for-place-order-button-in-magento/92767#92767)

Answer (score 1):

It happens in an ajax request, so you don't see the "echo" output in the frontend. If you inspect the response in the browser console you should see it.

I recommend to set up xdebug for step by step debugging. Then you can use a breakpoint instead of echo and exit. You also get information at runtime about variables and the call stack. It's really worth the initial effort.

Answer (score -1):

You have set the same observer name: "test". Try changing xml like this:

```
<events>
        <controller_front_init_before>
            <observers>
                <test>
                    <class>Foo_Test_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>capture</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                </test>
            </observers>
        </controller_front_init_before>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <test_order>
                    <class>Foo_Test_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>order</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                </test_order>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
**config.xml**

```
<events>
    <controller_front_init_before>
        <observers>
            <foo_test_capture>
                <class>Foo_Test_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>testCapture</method>
            </foo_test_capture>
        </observers>
    </controller_front_init_before>
    <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <foo_test_order>
                <class>Foo_Test_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>testOrder</method>
            </foo_test_order>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
```

**Observer.php**

```
class Foo_Test_Model_Observer
{

    public function testCapture(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        echo 'testCapture';die;

    }

    public function testOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

        echo 'testOrder';die;

    }
}
```

Comment: not working....

Comment: have you checked one event? Is working? suppose <events>
   <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <foo_test_order>
                <class>Foo_Test_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>testOrder</method>
            </foo_test_order>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
</events>

Comment: yes tried . I think what @Paw said bout conflicting is right.

Comment: single event working or not? I thinks event "sales_order_place_after" use any other module.

Comment: no single event <sales_order_place_after>  not working.