# Observer code for place order button in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, event-observer

Can anyone provide me the working code for Observer-Event Place Order button. I have tried with `**<sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>**`, `**<sales_order_save_after>**`and `**<sales_order_save_before>**` But none of them working. I tried in rwd theme without any third party OPC extenions.
This is my [2nd question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91373/sales-order-place-after-event-not-working) in this problem 
My aim is to check and get a particular cookie and save in the order placed table along with the order when **Place Order button** is clicked. I think i will be able to do the cookie part but I am unable to get the observer to run in the 1st place

Comment: In your Mage.php file, temporarily add `Mage::log($name);` statement in `dispatchEvent` method. This will generate the list of all events in a log file at every action you take. Now, click on the "Place Order" button and see if you are getting these events fired at first place.

Comment: yes i checked `<sales_order_save_before>` and `<sales_order_save_after>` occuring 2 times `<sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>` occuring 1 time.

Comment: Your previous code seems correct in that case. Update question with the exact code you are using for testing (With new event, I'd suggest working with `<sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>`). Only then, it will be possible to identify the issue. There is nothing new you'll find in others' code for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it work using `<sales_order_place_after>`. Hope this might help somebody facing same issue.